# Find $g(x)$ given $\int g(x)dx= \ln(\sin(x)) +C$

Tags: calculus

> Suppose the $g(x)$ is a function for which: $$\int g(x)dx=
> \ln(\sin(x)) +C$$ 
>   Find $g(x)$.

Should I get $g(x)$ by getting the derivative?

Comment: Yes. $\,\!\,\!$

Comment: though there is an issue when $\sin(x)$ is negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two functions$$ \int g(x)dx$$ and $$
\ln(\sin(x)) +C$$ where C is a constant. We Assume that these functions are well defined on a given domain.

According to the definition of an indefinite integral, $  \int g(x)dx$ is an antiderivative of g(x), that is derivative of  $  \int g(x)dx$ is g(x).

Note that you have a statement of equality between $ \int g(x)dx$ and
 $\ln(\sin(x)) +C$.

Therefore  $\ln(\sin(x)) +C$ is also an antiderivative of g(x). 
In order to find g(x) we need to differentiate its antiderivative, namely $\ln(\sin(x)) +C$.

Logarithmic differentiation  implies that $$ \frac {d}{dx} (\{ $\ln(\sin(x)) +C) = cot(x)$$ Therefore $$ g(x) = cot(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that 
$$\int g(x)\,dx=\log\sin x+C$$
Thus, 
$$g(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\left[\log\sin x+C\right]=\cot x$$
But there is a problem when $\sin x$ is negative, as $\log \sin x$ is then undefined. 
Maybe the problem statement was that 
$$\int g(x)\,dx=\log|\sin x|+C$$

Comment: Since $\ln(-x)=\pi i +\ln x$ we see that $ln x +C$ and $\ln |x|+C$ are really the same.